# MySQL connection failure from Android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, database-connection

I have an android project, in which I use code above to connect to remote MySQL database. This should handle login request, user should be authenticated in database stored information.

```
private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                url = new URL("http://remote.host/test/login.inc.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Append parameters to URL
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
```

I got error message, when try to send data from Android application. Connection refused as I see message in Android Monitor section. Permissions in Manifest file are OK for network connection.

config.inc.php file:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("OOPs something went wrong");
    }

?>
```

I get this error message in application:

> OOPs! Something went wrong.

Comment: What `$e->getMessage()` says?

Comment: Exception returns some information and everything you need is in `catch` section in `$e` variable. `echo $e->getMessage()` will show you where the problem is.